# Write a dao for elastic search using @Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a curl query that works perfectly

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/countries_reference_book/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"_source": {"includes": [ "tours.id"]},"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match":{ "departureDestination.departureCityId": "392" }},{ "match": { "departureDestination.destinationCountryId":  "146695" }}]}}}'
```

I want to use @Query to pass this query to a dao method my solution is as follows

```
@Query("{\"_source\": [ \"tours.id\"], \"query\":  {\"bool\": {\"must\": [{ \"match\":{ \"departureDestination.departureCityId\": ?0 }}, { \"match\": { \"departureDestination.destinationCountryId\": ?1 }}]}}}")
    List<Integer> getTourIdsBetweenDepartureCityAndDepartureCountry(int departureCityId, int destinationCountry);
```

but it doesnt work i get this error

```
org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: [_source] query malformed, no start_object after query name
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.parseInnerQueryBuilder(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:314) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
```

How can i write the query properly for dao, thanks